# Concept of Maximum Kinetic Energy

Tags: photoelectric-effect

What is the concept of maximum Kinetic energy of an electron when a photon is incident on a metal surface? Why the ejected electron can have a range of Kinetic Energy?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When a light of certain frequency is incident on a metal then the photoelectrons may get emitted by the metal.If the light has just threshold energy then photo electrons will have zero kinetic energy.If the wavelength is greater than threshold wavelength then photoelectrons will come out from the surface with some kinetic energy.The energy carried by photons is imparted to the electron,the electron would gain some kinetic energy and it may collide with some atoms in the metal,it loses some amount of kinetic energy to the atoms.If electrons do not collide with atoms then they would come out of the surface with maximum kinetic energy possible.